# How to use Apple Header doc for auto-generated documentation for iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, doxygen, autodoc

I have used Doxygen tool for document generation. But later on I have come to know that Apple itself provides "Documentation Set Guide".

Here is the reference link: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/Documentation_Sets/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005266-CH1-SW1

Is there anyone aware about this - how to use this and all? Whether it would be useful for autogenerated document creation?

Thanks in advance,

Mrunal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'docsets' are merely a way to package documentation and show it in XCode.
Doxygen has support for docsets, see
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/DoxygenXcode/_index.html
and
http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/ and
http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-ii/

If you want a tool that mimics Apples output (and care less about the features provided by doxygen) you could have a look at appledoc http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp

Comment: But how to use appledocapp? Is there any documentation available for that?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has it's own documentation generation tool. It's called [HeaderDoc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH345-SW1).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/usage/usage.html